# GCP Dataproc with Elasticsearch

Tags: apache-spark, elasticsearch, google-cloud-platform, jupyter, google-cloud-dataproc

I have a server in cloud (hidden behind VPN), on which I run single node Elasticsearch cluster. Within this instance of Elasticsearch I have an index (let's say it's named metrics-data) - it takes up 8GB in size.

I wanted to deploy GCP Dataproc cluster and perform some analysis using Spark with Jupyter on metrics-data index from this remote Elasticsearch cluster.

What's the simplest way to achieve this?

Answer (score 3):

Ok, so after all I decided to:

1. Dump indices from my Elasticsearch cluster to local computer using `elasticdump`:

   ```sh
   elasticdump --input=http://190.1.1.2:9200/metrics-data-* \
       --output=./data/metrics-data.json --sourceOnly --limit=10000
   ```
2. Upload files to Google Cloud Storage (GCS):

   ```sh
   for i in ./data/*; do gsutil cp $i gs://bucket-name/; done
   ```
3. Load data into Spark using [Cloud Storage connector](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/concepts/connectors/cloud-storage) (by default installed on GCP Dataproc)

It'd be even smoother if `elasticdump` had output directly to GCP (as it has for amazon S3).

Not sure if it's the simplest but works for me.